# dynamic sql rec php

Tags: php, sql, dynamic

Actualy this is my code to execute an sql select with php :

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spb', 'root', '');
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$table = explode(" where",explode("from ",$test)[1])[0];
$sql =  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table';";
$req = $bdd->query($sql);
$retour = "<table><tr><th></th><th>N° ligne</th>";
$titres = array();
while($resultat = $req->fetch()){
    array_push($titres,$resultat['COLUMN_NAME']);
    $retour.="<th>".$resultat['COLUMN_NAME']."</th>";
}

$retour.= "</tr>";
$req = $bdd->query($requette);
$cpt = 0;
$nbLigne = 0;
while($resultat = $req->fetch()){
    $nbLigne++;
    $retour .= "<tr><td class='boutonTouteLaCase' onclick='surlignerLigneProjets(this);'></td><td>$nbLigne</td>";
    for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($titres);$cpt++){
        $retour .= "<td>".$resultat[$titres[$cpt]]."</td>";
    }
    $retour .= "</tr>";
}
return $retour."</table>";
```

And it's working for this kind of req : `select * from utilisateurs`.
But when i add an extension like that : `select id from utilisateurs` or `select * from utilisateurs order by prenom`.
it don't works :/
Any idea ? thx

###################################################################

Edit : The question is : how to execute an sql req in a string ?

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin, with your database? If so, try running the query in there, in the SQL tab. See if it works, and if not, the see what error it gives you and let me know please. :)

Comment: The req is working in phpmyadmin. The problem is'nt here. Look at this link (screenshoot) to undersand : https://mega.co.nz/#!6EgURDRR!5YWXnV5fH9bwwgCnA8ftlxpiov5GWOyGJuR3KxJWIV0

Comment: could you upload your picture to http://tinypic.com/ or equivalent so I don't have to download it

Comment: http://fr.tinypic.com/r/344qpt0/8

Comment: Seems like a long shot but some databases have this enabled (don't ask me why), but try using caps for the queries. Change your query to this: SELECT * FROM utilisateurs ORDER BY prenom

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's the same result :/

Comment: What type of database do you have? What version etc.? This is very strange - Also try adding ASC at the end (ORDER BY prenom ASC)